# twilio getMessage method to return a sms status

Tags: c#, twilio

I am new to twilio. I just used the C# code from its website to successfully send out a SMS message to my phone. Now I need to get the feedback of the status of the message. However, if I use the code `message.status`, it only returns either `"accepted"` or `"queued"`.

I have been researching on this issue. I understand that there is a way of communication using `ngrok` to get `statusCallback`. However, as I continue to research on stackoverflow, someone mentioned that using twilio's `GetMessage` method will also give the message status.

Now I am wondering how to implement the `GetMessage` method to give the result. if I do this:

```
var result = twilio.GetMessage(message.Sid);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

it only returns `"Twilio.Message"`.

Please help.

Comment: when you hover over var..what is the datatype of results..? is it a List<T> if so use the string.Join function to return results 
something like this `var results = string.Join("," , results);`

Comment: lol, you are genius! it is a class!!!!!problem solved!!!!

Comment: how do I give you a thump up for editing and provide the hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Leejay Schmidt!!

All I need to do is to just add result.Status.